# "400: Unsupported service specified, INVALID_ARGUMENT" from Google Cloud Logging API

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to manually write a log entry using Google Cloud Logging API.

Before doing this via code, I am first trying to do it using the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/logging/v1beta3/). Here is a screen shot of the request I've built using this tool:

[image: Screenshot]

- In `projectsId` I have the Google Project Id that I've copied from the
  Google Developer Console.
- Likewise for `metadata.projectId`.
- In `metadata.userId` I have the Client Id of the same Service account that I'm using to authenticate (OAuth2) against the Google Logging API.
- Google Logging API is enabled for the project.
- The Service account belong to the project and has the "Can edit" permission.
- I'm 99% sure that I've setup OAuth2 correctly for the request.

When I execute this request, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": 
  {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unsupported service specified",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Why? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message was actually telling me exactly which argument was invalid - The `serviceName` I supplied was bogus ("test").

As soon as I set the serviceName to be "compute.googleapis.com", the problem went away and I received a 200 status code indicating success.

Comment: Did your log show up in the Developer Console -> Monitoring -> Logs viewer ? I get the 200 success status code when submitting logs, but the logs don't appear in the viewer . . .

Comment: OK I figured out why the logs weren't showing: the app must be uploaded and run in the Appengine, otherwise the logs don't get saved. (it doesn't seem to work in localhost dev_appserver or in the API Explorer)